# myFirstApp is not there

Tags: android

I was working on the "getting started" on the Android Website but I cannot manage to build my first application (a simple hello world).
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I get this messages:

```
C:\Users\vbiscione\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:820
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
creating window 61 83 462 820
```

When the emulator loads, and I swipe it up, my app isn't there.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using Android Studio. I did not change the initial file at all (a blank activity)

Comment: Check [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-hax-is-working-and-emulator-runs-in-fast-virt-mode-emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered) out.

Comment: Done. I don't get any error, but the app is still not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me time to time. What I observed that is on the first time that the emulator try to run an app. It sometimes not success. My assumption that there are many services loading up at first run which could cause the ADB to think that the emulator is not responsive then terminate the app launching.

All you need to do is leave the emulator running and swiped to unlock the screen to keep it ready for launching an app for the second time. Then try to launch the app again. The app should appears on screen smoothly.

HTH

Comment: What does `HTH` mean?

Comment: Hope this helps. HTH :D